# Getting a Node from XML in Java not working

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML that has something like this:

`<ListOfErrors>
    <Error>
        <ErrorCode>1</ErrorCode>
        <Severity>Critical</Severity>
    </Error>
    <Error>
        <ErrorCode>15414</ErrorCode>
        <Severity>Non-Critical</Severity>
    </Error> 
</ListOfErrors>`

I'm trying that, by receiving the error code I can retrieve the other values under the Error. For example, I receive error 1, and I get to know the severity.

I'm doing this:

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new File("file.xml"));

        String xPathExpression = "//Error[ErrorCode=1]";

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(xPathExpression,
                document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println(nodes.getLength());
        Element firstElement = (Element)nodes.item(0);                              
        System.out.println("Severity"+firstElement.getAttribute("Severity"));
```

I know it's not working, but I don't know what I am missing, the xPathExpression is working correctly because if I leave it only as //Error and I print the nodes.getlength then I get all error types.
Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You're retrieving the Error node with ErrorCode = 1, but that node has no attributes, so firstElement.getAttribute("Severity") won't retrieve anything.

The Severity is actually a child node of Error, not an attribute. To get the value, you'll either need to cycle through the child nodes (firstElement.getChildNodes() ) or change the XPath to get the Severity directly ("//Error[ErrorCode=1]/Severity")